# Pandas importing FRED data (pandas.io.data or pandas_datareader)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Very simple question here which i could not find the answer for reading the docs (below is an excerpt):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web    # pandas 0.19.x and later
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
gdp = web.DataReader("GDP", "fred", start, end)
```

> Documentation:  http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html

Note that if you have an older version of pandas you should instead do the 
following import:

```
import pandas.io.data as web    # pandas 0.18.x and earlier
```

So my question is ... where can one find a list of the acceptable parameters (like GDP), and what they correspond to?  Even GDP has many different flavors - and FRED lists BEA Account Code's to clarify so I'm not sure how these are reconciled.

Comment: Have you checked the docs? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html

Comment: I don't think you read my question, the first sentence says I tried referencing the docs.

Comment: sorry for that. Just skimmed over the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bring back an old topic, but I figured out a way to find the economic codes for the pandas_datareader using FRED data. To do this:
1. install the package 'fredapi' using conda install or pip install at [https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fredapi]
2. Sign up for a FRED API key on the FRED website
3. Use the function:

```
from fredapi import Fred as fred
fred = fred(api_key='your_api_key')
fred.search('natural gas exports').T
```

It will output a variety of codes and descriptions depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: do you know if pdr allows u to pass in the units you would like the data in?

Answer (score 1):

These are [ticker symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol), basically stocks. You can find several lists online e.g. [eodata](http://eoddata.com/symbols.aspx), though I'm not sure where or if there is a definitive list for FRED (or the other data sources)...

*[GDP](https://www.google.com/search?q=GDP+ticker) is Goodrich Petroleum Corporation.*

Answer (score 1):

Nobody posted a relevant answer so through trial and error I figured this out

There doesn't appear to be a repository or search function as far as I can tell in the library, but the relevant tickers are displayed at the top of each indicator when you search for them in FRED.  For example, if you search "Real Gross Domestic Product", once you get that chart pulled up in FRED, the first paragraph shows a ticker "GDPC1" which is what you need.

Also, you can pass a list of tickers in like so to get multiple series added to your dataframe:

`In [32]: gdp=web.DataReader(ticker_list, "fred", start, end)`

Answer (score 1):

The [FRED API](https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/) includes full text search, and the wrappers [fredapi](https://github.com/mortada/fredapi) and [fred](https://github.com/zachwill/fred) leverage this functionality to return data series identifiers against your query.

You just need to sign up for an [API key](https://research.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/api_key.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like @Solaxun I couldn't find a good way to search for the relevant codes other than going to FRED.  For example, I clicked around to get the percentage change in GDP here:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A191RL1Q225SBEA

And you can take that code at the end of the URL `A191RL1Q225SBEA` and plug it in to get the series like this:

```
gdp_pct_change = web.DataReader("A191RL1Q225SBEA", "fred", start, end)
```

Here are some other codes for convenience and to give you a sense the breadth of data you can get there.  Note that for many series like GDP there are many variants (seasonally vs not seasonally adjusted, real vs nominal, etc.) so there often is no substitute for just going directly to FRED and reading the exact descriptions.

- Real Gross Domestic Product (A191RL1Q225SBEA) -- percent change
- Real Gross Domestic Product (GDPC1) -- dollars
- Federal Debt: Total Public Debt as Percent of Gross Domestic Product (GFDEGDQ188S)
- Consumer Price Index for All Urban Consumers: All Items (CPIAUCSL)

Employment related stats:

- Civilian Unemployment Rate (UNRATE)
- All Employees: Total Nonfarm Payrolls (PAYEMS)
- 4-Week Moving Average of Initial Claims (IC4WSA)

Interest Rates:

- 10-Year Treasury Constant Maturity Rate (DGS10)
- Effective Federal Funds Rate (FEDFUNDS)
- 3-Month London Interbank Offered Rate (LIBOR), based on U.S. Dollar (USD3MTD156N)

Stock Indices:

- S&P 500 (SP500)
- Nikkei Stock Average, Nikkei 225 (NIKKEI225)

Answer (score 0):

FRED allows you to search for the ticker of any of the economic variables they have by using this api:
(remember to change the api_key to your own api_key)

'https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/search?api_key=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456&search_text=canada'

At the 'search_text' parameter you can change to the word related to the ticker you are looking for.

You can use the library request to download the data and the library pandas to work on downloaded data.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Ep-CmoqWxrMU8HshxthRcdRW8IsXvh3n2-ZHVCzqzQ/edit#gid=1855920257) - tikers. Usefull columns:

> 1. ISIN - this is a unique identifier for all stocks Worldwide
> 2. MIC - this is an identifier for the exchange the stocks are traded on
> 3. Subtitle - looks like the market sector
> 4. Symbol is the market ticker
> 5. The title, long title and account currency

[here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ant358/ColabGitHub/blob/main/notebooks/How_you_can_use_Python_to_find_the_top_ten_momentum_stocks.ipynb#scrollTo=nYPAFcQaGYra) - how you can programmically load & plot *top-10 Momentum Stocks* using `yfinance`

p.s. I didn't check it for `FRED`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OPs question: "Where can one find a list of the acceptable parameters (like GDP), and what they correspond to?"

I am not aware of a published list of parameters to be used for extracting data through the FRED API.

However, from the FRED API documentation I can see how to build one.
The FRED API documentation is terse, so please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something in my explanations below.

- FRED Home Webpage: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/
- FRED API main documentation: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/

First consider the following terms and concepts that I took away from reading the docs:

> - The data points we seek are referred to by FRED as data "Observations".
> - These "Observations" are available/referred to/identified by a 'parameter', 'symbol', 'label', 'field', `id`, etc... that is referred to by FRED as a "Series".
> - Data "Series" are bottom most nodes of a tree type 'structure' called "Categories"
> - One traverses down a hierarchy of "Categories" to find the "Series" along with metadata provided on that "Series".

Looking at this from a top-down tree:

> - You will see "Categories" which contain child "Categories" that eventually contain data "Series" whose `id` you use to query the data "Observations".
> - The API provides endpoints for exploring the tree of "Categories" to finally see children "Series" where one would access the "Observations"
> - The API also provides endpoints for exploring what the parent "Categories" of particular child "Category" or "Series" `id` are.
> - The top most root "Category" has a `category_id=0`.

On the FRED API main documentation page you will see various endpoints defined under the page headings of "Categories" and "Series". These return information as defined on the page there. This is where I get the query string syntax used below. (Please Note: I will not be explaining "Releases", "Sources" or "Tags" in this writeup.)

To build yourself a table of "Category" and "Series" information we simply transverse the tree of Categories and Series, collecting the information returned along the way.

Below is a top down example that will show you how to do it. Hopefully you'll gain better understanding of the API documentation along the way. I will simply be using the `requests` package and the FRED API endpoints. I will not be using the `pandas-datareader` or any of the FRED API packages you can find on PYPI or GIT. They are not needed.

#### Find the "Series" id for the "Federal Funds Effective Rate"

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: import requests
In [4]: FRED_URL = 'https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred'
In [5]: API_KEY = 'XXX_YOUR_API_KEY_XXX'

# Verify category_id=0 is top parent and get it's children

In [6]: requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/category?category_id=0&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json').json()
Out[6]: {'categories': [{'id': 0, 'name': 'Categories', 'parent_id': 0}]}
# Yes, 0 is the top level category

In [7]: requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/category/children?category_id=0&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json').json()
Out[7]:
{'categories': [
   {'id': 32991, 'name': 'Money, Banking, & Finance', 'parent_id': 0},
   {'id': 10, 'name': 'Population, Employment, & Labor Markets', 'parent_id': 0},
   {'id': 32992, 'name': 'National Accounts', 'parent_id': 0},
   {'id': 1, 'name': 'Production & Business Activity', 'parent_id': 0},
   {'id': 32455, 'name': 'Prices', 'parent_id': 0},
   {'id': 32263, 'name': 'International Data', 'parent_id': 0},
   {'id': 3008, 'name': 'U.S. Regional Data', 'parent_id': 0},
   {'id': 33060, 'name': 'Academic Data', 'parent_id': 0}]}
# These are the top level categories, the children of category_id=0
```

- You should notice that the top level 'categories' output here mimic what is shown on the FRED Home Webpage when you follow the "Categories" link.
- Let's continue down the sub-categories looking for the "Federal Funds Effective Rate" Series.
- Get the children of the {'id': 32991, 'name': 'Money, Banking, & Finance', 'parent_id': 0} Category shown in the output above.

```
In [8]: requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/category/children?category_id=32991&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json').json()
Out[8]:
{'categories': [
   {'id': 22, 'name': 'Interest Rates', 'parent_id': 32991},
   {'id': 15, 'name': 'Exchange Rates', 'parent_id': 32991},
   {'id': 24, 'name': 'Monetary Data', 'parent_id': 32991},
   {'id': 46, 'name': 'Financial Indicators', 'parent_id': 32991},
   {'id': 23, 'name': 'Banking', 'parent_id': 32991},
   {'id': 32360, 'name': 'Business Lending', 'parent_id': 32991},
   {'id': 32145, 'name': 'Foreign Exchange Intervention', 'parent_id': 32991,
     'notes': "In addition to the listed daily intervention series, intra-day series from the Swiss National Bank are available at: \r\nhttp://research.stlouisfed.org/fei/\r\n\r\nUnited Kingdom foreign exchange intervention data can be downloaded from Her Majesty's Treasury at the following:\r\nhttp://www.hm-treasury.gov.uk"}
]}
```

- The output above shows that we found more sub-categories.
- Once again, this structure should look familiar to that presented on the FRED webpage under "Categories" as you drill down further on the corresponding links there.
- Notice above that we now see a "notes" key for some of categories. This kind of metadata is helpful along the way, especially when we get all the way down to the actual Series level.
- Let's continue going down and see what is in the {'id': 22, 'name': 'Interest Rates', 'parent_id': 32991} Category

```
In [9]: requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/category/children?category_id=22&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json').json()
Out[9]:
{'categories': [
  {'id': 34009, 'name': 'AMERIBOR Benchmark Rates', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 33058, 'name': 'Automobile Loan Rates', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 51, 'name': 'Bankers Acceptance Rate', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 121, 'name': 'Certificates of Deposit', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 120, 'name': 'Commercial Paper', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 32348, 'name': 'Corporate Bonds', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 33059, 'name': 'Credit Card Loan Rates', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 34005, 'name': 'EONIA Rates', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 34007, 'name': 'Euro Short-Term Rate', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 32298, 'name': 'Eurodollar Deposits', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 118,
    'name': 'FRB Rates - discount, fed funds, primary credit',
    'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 33056, 'name': 'Interest Checking Accounts', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 33446, 'name': 'Interest Rate Spreads', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 32299, 'name': 'Interest Rate Swaps', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 32995, 'name': 'Long-Term Securities', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 33055, 'name': 'Money Market Accounts', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 114, 'name': 'Mortgage Rates', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 33057, 'name': 'Personal Loan Rates', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 117, 'name': 'Prime Bank Loan Rate', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 33491, 'name': 'Saving Accounts', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 34003, 'name': 'SONIA Rates', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 116, 'name': 'Treasury Bills', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 115, 'name': 'Treasury Constant Maturity', 'parent_id': 22},
  {'id': 82,
   'name': 'Treasury Inflation-Indexed Securities',
   'parent_id': 22}]}
```

- The output above shows that we found more sub-categories.

> - So far we have explored the children of top level category_id=0,
> - then we got the children of 'id': 32991, 'name': 'Money, Banking, & Finance' Category
> - then got the children of 'id': 22, 'name': 'Interest Rates' Category

- Now, from the above output, let's get the children of Category {'id': 118, 'name': 'FRB Rates - discount, fed funds, primary credit', 'parent_id': 22}

```
In [10]: requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/category/series?category_id=118&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json').json()
Out[10]:
{'realtime_start': '2023-12-30',
 'realtime_end': '2023-12-30',
 'order_by': 'series_id',
 'sort_order': 'asc',
 'count': 73,
 'offset': 0,
 'limit': 1000,
 'seriess': [
   "LIST OF DICT PROVIDING INFORMATION ON SERIES CHILDREN OF THIS CATEGORY"]}
```

- This time we got a whole bunch of output that I've replaced with the string "LIST OF DICT..." above.
- These are the Series fields that are available under `category_id=118` that we queried above.
- If you are drilling down on the FRED Website links while running the code I'm showing here, you should see very similar information...

I've truncated the above output on the dictionary key `seriess`, which contains a list of dictionaries.

- From above you see that there is a count of 73 Series (`seriess`) children under this Category.
- The keys:values of the 73 dicts in this list are the metadata information regarding each of the 73 Series.
- Below is a line of code to query FRED for the children Series under category_id=118 just like above, and dump all that json which was truncated above into a pd.DataFrame.
- Once all the information is in a DataFrame you can roll it around however you like to learn about what Series you want to extract Observations for.

```
In [11]: FRB_df = pd.DataFrame((requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/category/series?category_id=118&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json').json())['seriess'])

In [12]: FRB_df
Out[12]:
           id realtime_start realtime_end  ... popularity group_popularity                                              notes
0         CDC     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...          2                2                                                NaN
1     DDISCRT     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         10               13  For more information, see http://www.federalre...
2     DFEDTAR     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         56               56  Data for the period prior to 1994 come from th...
3    DFEDTARL     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         61               61  This series represents lower limit of the fede...
4    DFEDTARU     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         79               79  This series represents upper limit of the fede...
..        ...            ...          ...  ...        ...              ...                                                ...
68     SOFR99     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         28               28                                                NaN
69  SOFRINDEX     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         61               61  As an extension of the additional documentatio...
70    SOFRVOL     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         46               46                                                NaN
71    WDISCRT     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...          1               13  Averages of daily figures. For more informatio...
72   WPCREDIT     2023-12-30   2023-12-30  ...         14               59  This data represent rate charged for discounts...

[73 rows x 16 columns]
```

- Notice in this output how the `id` are now string identifiers for the individual Series names and not numbers like when we were traversing the Categories.
- These are the "parameters" asked for in the OP question way up top.

We can see all the 'keys' from the Series dictionaries as they are now our DataFrame column names. This metadata will further define each Series and help you understand which Series you want to extract Observations on.

```
In [13]: FRB_df.columns
Out[13]:
Index(['id', 'realtime_start', 'realtime_end', 'title', 'observation_start',
       'observation_end', 'frequency', 'frequency_short', 'units',
       'units_short', 'seasonal_adjustment', 'seasonal_adjustment_short',
       'last_updated', 'popularity', 'group_popularity', 'notes'],
      dtype='object')
```

By looking at the `id`, `title` and `notes` columns below we see that there are several Series with the title "Federal Funds Effective Rate" in this Category so we're going to have to look a little closer at metadata of these Series to see which one we really want.

```
In [14]: FRB_df.loc[FRB_df.title == "Federal Funds Effective Rate"][['id', 'title', 'notes']]
Out[14]:
              id                         title                                              notes
5            DFF  Federal Funds Effective Rate  For additional historical federal funds rate d...
18      FEDFUNDS  Federal Funds Effective Rate  Averages of daily figures.   For additional hi...
33            FF  Federal Funds Effective Rate  Averages of daily figures.   For additional hi...
56     RIFSPFFNA  Federal Funds Effective Rate  Averages of daily figures.   For additional hi...
57     RIFSPFFNB  Federal Funds Effective Rate  For additional historical federal funds rate d...
58  RIFSPFFNBWAW  Federal Funds Effective Rate  Averages of daily figures.   For additional hi...
```

- You can play around with this DataFrame from here and see what you can see.
- You can consult the FRED website for definitions on metadata keys that are now your column names or whatever else you need.
- I recommend picking out columns and sorting the DataFrame however makes sense for you, then exporting to excel where it can be easier read.

##### What you should take away from what we've done thus far is that you can transverse the "Categories" tree down to the child "Series" where you can find the "Series" `id` and other metadata that will allow you to understand what "Observation" you wish to extract from FRED.

##### If you so desire, go ahead do some recursion or build some loops to transverse all of the "Categories" tree to find all the "Series" information and format that into your own handy mega-list. This is what the OP was requesting above.

---

What I've been doing with the DataFrame above is:

1. Remove any `\n` or `,` from the `notes` column.
2. Sort the DataFrame by `last_updated` and `popularity` columns as that's what I like.
   Note: I convert the `last_updated` column to `dt.date` without time, so that sorting on the `popularity` field makes sense. This way I can see daily, weekly, monthly update groupings.
3. I pick out the DataFrame's columns I'm interested in and export for ease of reading in excel.

Here's some quick code:

```
In [15]: cols = ['id', 'title', 'observation_start', 'observation_end', 'frequency',
         'units', 'units_short', 'seasonal_adjustment_short','last_updated',
         'popularity','notes']

In [16]: FRB_df['notes'] = FRB_df.notes.str.replace("\n", " ")

In [17]: FRB_df['last_updated'] = pd.to_datetime(FRB_df.last_updated, utc=True).dt.date

In [18]: FRB_df.loc[:, cols].sort_values(['last_updated','popularity'], axis=0, ascending=False).to_csv('FRB-118_seriesInfo.csv')
```

Now I have a handy list of the "Series" under this "Category" with metadata fields to help me determine which "Series" I wish to extract "Observations" on.

---

As a little `pd` & `requests` exercise, lets say were interested in seeing "Observations" on:

- DFF = Federal Funds Effective Rate
- DFEDTARU  = Federal Funds Target Range - Upper Limit
- DFEDTARL  = Federal Funds Target Range - Lower Limit

A simple request for "Observations" on 'DFF' would look as follows:

```
In [19]: tmp_json = requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/series/observations?series_id=DFF&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json&observation_start=2023-12-01').json()
In [20]: DFF_series = pd.DataFrame(tmp_json['observations'], columns=['date','value']).rename(columns={'value':'DFF'}).set_index('date').DFF
```

Note that specifying only a `observation_start` date, all data since that date is requested.

To get more than one Series I typically just loop through the requests and merge the results together...

```
In [21]: from functools import reduce
In [22]: series = ['DFF', 'DFEDTARU', 'DFEDTARL']
In [23]: tmp_dfs = []
In [24]: for ser in series:
    ...:     tmp_json = tmp_json = requests.get(f'{FRED_URL}/series/observations?series_id={ser}&api_key={API_KEY}&file_type=json&observation_start=2023-12-01').json()
    ...:     tmp_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(tmp_json['observations'], columns=['date', 'value']).rename(columns={'value': ser}))

In [25]: DFF_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['date'], how='outer'), tmp_dfs)
```