# How can I get the data for the nasdaq index using the pandas data_reader?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Using the Pandas `data_reader`, I can get the historical stock information in the form of a `DataFrame` such as:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'morningstar', start, end)
```

Can i get the composite data for the `NASDAQ` index in this way, rather than just one stock?

Comment: You need all ticker name then .

Comment: I tried using the ticker symbol "^IXIC" and I also tried "IXIC" in place of "TSLA". Neither worked. I don't think the DataReader can be used in that manner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas importing FRED data (pandas.io.data or pandas\_datareader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445106/pandas-importing-fred-data-pandas-io-data-or-pandas-datareader)  Specifically, try this code via the FRED interface:  NASDAQCOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asked for it using the `pandas_datareader` module.  It used to be very straightforward to get this information using `pandas_datareader` before Yahoo! altered their API in late 2017 and the csv endpoint was retired.   More on some these developments can be in the `pandas_datareader` docs ([link here](http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html)).

There is another fairly straightforward option for getting the NASDAQ Composite index into a dataframe.  That is, to use the `Quandl` module for this purpose ([Link here](https://www.quandl.com/tools/python)).

Here's how you can use Quandl

```
import datetime, quandl

ndq = quandl.get("NASDAQOMX/COMP-NASDAQ", 
              trim_start='2018-03-01', 
              trim_end='2018-04-03')

print(ndq.head(4))
```

With expected Output:

```
Trade Date    Index Value     High        Low         Total Market Value

2018-03-01    7180.56         7307.84    7117.66      1.096433e+13
2018-03-02    7257.87         7267.19    7084.83      1.108254e+13
2018-03-05    7330.70         7350.07    7205.31      1.119375e+13
2018-03-06    7372.01         7378.03    7319.68      1.125703e+13
```

Comment: what is the for nasdaq-100 using quandl? having a hard time finding it